# Creating class instance with arguments - strange "use of undefined constant" notice

Tags: php, class, oop, undefined, notice

I'm instantiating a class, and getting a very weird 'notice' as a result.

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant int - assumed 'int' in /var/www/html/symbiostock3/wp-content/plugins/ss-core/includes/class-product.php on line 219
```

**Why is this happening?**

Line 219 has this class instance:

```
$something = new Some_Product(1783, 3);
```

To narrow it down, I split up the code onto separate lines, to see which part of this line is acting strange.

```
$something = new 
        Some_Product(
        1783,
        3);
```

And the 'notice' persists `Some_Product` instance.

I cannot understand why its assuming a 'constant' when I've properly declared the class right above it! Like so:

```
class Some_Product{

    //buncha stuff

    public function __construct($var1, $var2){

        //buncha stuff

    }

    //I like pie...

}
```

I'm living in the twighlight zone of PHP where reality seems bent.

I'd love to have this mystery solved.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when I defined variables I used "int" as a placeholder like this:

```
$somevar = int;
```

Although the error was occurring farther back, for some reason it was showing up on the line the class instance was created.